# Numeric, alpha numeric, numeric alpha sort

Tags: formula, lotus

I have documents within a lotus notes application that has a control number.
  The control number can be either 4 digit number, alpha character and 3 digit number or 3
  digit number and an alpha character.
  Examples of the type of control number:  8321  or A310  or 312C

They are wanting the view to be sorted in this manner:
  First 4 digit number in order
  Next by Alpha & 3 digit number in order
  Next by 3 digit number & alpha character

I have tried a number of things but cannot get the view to display in the manner they want 
  it in.

Any ideas how to do this is much appreciated.

Thank you,
  Jean

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden Sort- Column before your "visible" column with the value.

Try this formula in that column (replace YourField appropriately):

```
_TestVal := @Text(YourField);
_firstSort := @If( @Matches( _TestVal ; "{0-9}{0-9}{0-9}{0-9}" ) ; "1"; 
                   @Matches( _TestVal ; "{A-Z}{0-9}{0-9}{0-9}" ) ; "2" ; "3" );

_secondSort := @If( _firstSort = "3" ; @Right( _TestVal ; 1) ; "0" );
_firstSort + _secondSort + _TestVal
```

It prepends the Value with "10", "20" or "3A" ("3B", "3C"...), depending of the @Matches and sorts the rest as Notes would by default...

Comment: Thank you so very much for the information! This is perfect, but one quick question, when it sorts the Numeric/Alpha field, is there a way to get the sort to go in order by alphabetical such as 109A, 110A, 111A and than on to 109B, 110B, & 111B?  Otherwise, this is working great for the sorting.